# org-odt-export subscript bug

Tags: org-mode, odt

According to the documentation, the following setting enables subscript only in
the form like ‘a_{b}’.

```
  (setq org-use-sub-superscripts nil)
```

However, in 'a_b', 'b' is still exported as subscript. How to export '_' as
underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation in org-mode 8.2.10 the option that controls the export is `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` and not `org-use-sub-superscript`.

Answer (score 1):

The the curly bracket syntax has effect only on display. If you have complex sub/superscripts or have filenames with underscore (_), set `org-use-sub-superscript` to `{}`.

As pointed out in the other answer, the variable that affects export is `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`. Put this into your emacs config file and evaluate it for immediate effect:

```
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

or to set it only for the current buffer by adding the following line to the beginning of the file and activate it with `C-c C-c`.

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

Comment: If you want to disable it, you must set it to nil, not t.

Comment: That's right, I corrected the the option ^ to nil.